# Re-enabling right-click on web page: "Void document oncontextmenu null" trick not working

Tags: javascript, contextmenu, addeventlistener

For testing purposes, I have disabled the right click function on a web page by adding the following JavaScript snippet code:

`document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());`

So far, so good.

Now, to re-enable the option using a code method, it is supposed to be enough to just type `javascript:void(document.oncontextmenu=null);` in the address bar of your Browser and press Enter. But this method seems not be working anymore. I do not know what is wrong with it and wonder if there is any similar alternative way, except toggling off JavaScript in Chrome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method can be removed with [`removeEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) method only

If you need your code working you need to assign the event with the [`oncontextmenu`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oncontextmenu) property

I mean that

```
document.oncontextmenu = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

It will work.